# Why is my controller requesting frontend_dev.php in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, controller

http://localhost/frontend_dev.php/1

Why is the above request redirected to `frontend_dev.php` instead of `index.php`?

I've read the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I'm understanding it correctly,if the requested file doesn't exist,it should be redirected to `index.php`,how can `frontend_dev.php` be run in the case above?

Comment: is the rewrite working on other urls?

Comment: Of course,it's working,but I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 6):

You have specified http://localhost/frontend_dev.php/1 as the URL - Apache simply serves up `frontend_dev.php` as you are explicitly asking for that file in the URL. Change your URL to http://localhost/index.php/1 to see the production controller.

The rewrite rules deal **only** with URLs that don't mention a front controller at all, ie. http://localhost/1 - the rewrite rules are not being parsed at all for the URL you initially provided, as Apache detected the frontend_dev.php file and found no matching rewrite rule to parse.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Because `frontend_dev.php` does exist, it **is** executed. And no redirect is performed.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be `frontend_dev.php/1` ?

Comment: No it shouldn't. I can't exactly say why, but probably Apache docs could shed the light on this issue.